# Dynamic grid system with different widths css3?

Tags: html, css

I need to perform a dynamic grid system like this:
[image: Grid system]

Each section is an article that contains an image, a title and a link/button to that article.
The problem is that each section is loaded dynamically and i only have the html of the section so i need to put each section on the correct position dynamically from the CSS. The one i know is that there are 5 sections.

The html code of each section and the container of all the sections is this:

```
<section class="scroll"> 
    <!-- ARTICLES -->
        <!-- ARTICLE -->
        <div class="article-content">
            <img class="article-image" src="${item.imgPath}" />
            <div class="article-texts">
                <h1 class="article-title">${item.title}</h1>
                <a class="article-button" href="${item.link}.html" role="button">Read Article ></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <!-- END ARTICLE -->
    <!-- END ARTICLES -->
</section>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Comment: What have you tried? Do the boxes always have to be in those positions? Provide a jsfiddle to show us what you've tried.

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/GridGallery/

Comment: @i7nvd yes, i have tried but i'm new to css and i could figure out how to position those div's like that (the div's always must have in that positions).

Comment: see this two link hope your issue is solve

Comment: https://github.com/kombai/freewall this another for you

Comment: Can you add some wrapper divs around the sections?

Comment: @Pangloss wrapper divs? what do you mean?

Comment: i.e. wrap the top 3 sections intro a div, wrap bottom 2 sections into another.

Comment: The sections are loaded dynamically, i don't have them when i write the HTML

Comment: Are you sure of the width and heights of those sections? Are the dimensions predetermined?

Comment: What do you mean by *dynamic* grid system? Do you mean responsive? I understand that the HTML content might change but it sounds like the grid should remain the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A solution only involving floats can reproduce your layout. Compatibility IE8+ (and even below but nobody cares). Pseudo-class `:nth-child()` (compat. IE9+) is used here to give an arbitrary width and height for demo, you'll have your own layout in real conditions.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
div { width: 360px; }
section { border: 1px solid #666; }
.left { float: left; }
.right { float: right; }
.clear { clear: both; }
section:nth-child(1) { width: 240px; height: 240px; }
section:nth-child(2) { width: 120px; height: 100px; }
section:nth-child(3) { width: 120px; height: 80px; }
section:nth-child(4) { width: 200px; height: 120px; }
section:nth-child(5) { width: 160px; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<div>
    <section class="left">1</section>
    <section class="right">2</section>
    <section class="right">3</section>
    <section class="left clear">4</section>
    <section class="right">5</section>
</div>
```

Comment: You will have to remove the `nth-child` pseudo-class, before this will be supported by anything below IE8.

Comment: @AlexW this pseudo is used for demo purpose, to give width and height to the 5 blocks. Let's hope a fixed height isn't used in real conditions... I edited to make it clear

Comment: Just for transparency's sake, I did not downvote this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the dimensions of your `section`s, you can use a fixed width container and `float` the `section`s inside that. Clear the `float` on the fourth section.

**Example Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mbuf9957/3/

**Example Snippet**:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin:0; }
div { width: 380px; overflow: hidden; }
section { border: 1px solid #666; float: left; }
section:nth-child(1) { width: 240px; height: 240px; }
section:nth-child(2) { width: 120px; height: 120px; }
section:nth-child(3) { width: 120px; height: 120px; }
section:nth-child(4) { width: 120px; height: 120px; clear: left; }
section:nth-child(5) { width: 240px; height: 120px; }
```

```html
<div>
    <section>1</section>
    <section>2</section>
    <section>3</section>
    <section>4</section>
    <section>5</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged this as CSS3, I think [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) would be an option.  You could set `display:flex` on the parent and then have percentage widths for each box's [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) and set the `flex-grow` property to the amount of space, relative to other boxes, you want them to take up in the container and set `flex-shrink` to `0` since you don't need them to shrink.

**CSS/HTML**:

```css
.grid-system {
    /* Uncomment the next line to see the container */
    /* border:1px solid black; */
}
.grid-system .box-width-2 {
    border:1px solid black;
    -webkit-flex:2 0 65%;
    flex: 2 0 65%;
}
.grid-system .box-width-1 {
    border:1px solid black;
    -webkit-flex:1 0 32%;
    flex: 1 0 32%;
}
.grid-system .box-height-2 {
    -webkit-flex-grow:2;
    flex-grow:2;
}
.grid-system .box-height-1 {
    -webkit-flex-grow:1;
    flex-grow:1;
}
.grid-system .flex-row {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow:row nowrap;
    flex-flow:row nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content:flext-start;
    justify-content:flex-start;
}
.grid-system .flex-column {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow:column nowrap;
    flex-flow:column nowrap;
    width:32%;
}
.grid-system .flex-row > div {
    margin:0.5%
}
.grid-system  .box-width-1.box-height-1 {
    margin-bottom:0.5%;
    -webkit-flex-grow:1;
    flex-grow:1;
}
.grid-system .box-width-1.box-height-1.end {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-system">
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="box-width-2 box-height-2">1</div>
        <div class="flex-column">
            <div class="box-width-1 box-height-1">2</div>
            <div class="box-width-1 box-height-1 end">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="box-width-1">4</div>
        <div class="box-width-2">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky3L4yLr/3/)